# cant load dll that contains call to CreateProcessAsUserW

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary, createprocessasuser

i have a program that loads dlls, all dlls have only one simple c function "run". one dll contains call to CreateProcessAsUserW and when i try to load it, LoadLibrary reports error 127 "ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND". when i comment it out, dll loads normally and is callable. i was running dependency walker on this dll and CreateProcessAsUserW is marked red with error:

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
```

this problem does not occur when using CreateProcessAsUserA, only when using CreateProcessAsUserW.

```
my setup:
xp sp3 updated to max
mingw64, gcc 4.9.1
```

i also have static libs and static runtime turned off

whats the source of my problem? how can i fix this so CreateProcessAsUserW will work?

Comment: This is an old Cygwin post about the CreateProcessAsUserW entry point moving, it might be some help. https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-08/msg00672.html  Can you check which dll your applications thinks CreateProcessAsUserW should be found in, it should be advapi32.dll by my reading of the docs.

Comment: yes, this link describes my problem, dependency walker showed that CreateProcessAsUserW should be in kernel32 but its not there, so i linked advapi32.a before kernel32.a and things are working now